# How to store download urls and retrieve them from a collection

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I have a form that sends data and images to firebase (firestore). I created a collection that only stores the urls. What I need is a way to query the different images urls based on a document reference ID because in my hierarchy, the last collection creates documents with unique ID and I'm unable to query them in order to get the image url.

Form.js

```
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { db, storage } from "../../firebase";
import {
  addDoc,
  collection,
  doc,
  updateDoc,
} from "@firebase/firestore";
import { getDownloadURL, ref, uploadBytes } from "@firebase/storage";
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react";


function Form() {

  const { data: session } = useSession();
  const Images = useSelector((state) => state.draggedImages.images);
  const imageTarget = Images.length - 1;


  const SendPost = async () => {
    const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, "posts"), {
      id: session.user.uid, 
      AdDescription: description,
  
    });

    Images[imageTarget].map((Img) => {
      const imageRef = ref(storage, `posts/${docRef.id}/${Img.name}`);
      uploadBytes(imageRef, Img, "data_url").then(async () => {
        const downloadURL = await getDownloadURL(imageRef);
        await updateDoc(doc(db, "posts", docRef.id), {
          image: downloadURL,
        });

        // ---------------HERE IS THE PROBLEM--------------
        await addDoc(collection(db, "ImageUrl", docRef.id, "Urls"), {
            image: downloadURL,
          });
        // --------------------------------------------------
       
      });
    }); 
  };
}

export default Form;
```

upon uploading the images, I have to fetch them into a carousel.

Carousel.js

```
import {
    collection,
    doc,
    onSnapshot,
    orderBy,
    query,
    getDocs,
  } from "@firebase/firestore";
  import { useRouter } from "next/router";
  import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
  import { db } from "../../firebase";
  
  function Carousel() {
    const [FetchedImages, setFetchedImages] = useState([]);
    const router = useRouter();
    const { id } = router.query;

    useEffect(
      () =>
        onSnapshot(doc(db, `ImageUrl/${id}`), (snapshot) => {
          setFetchedImages(snapshot.data());
        }),
      [db]
    );
  
    console.log("fetched : ", FetchedImages); // returns undefined 
 
  }
  
  export default Carousel;
```

[image: Files hierarchy]

Comment: Returns undefined? Is that the problem you are having fetching the ImageUrl/id document?

Answer (score 2):

The defined hierarchy in the Form.js is pretty fine. The problem was actually the way to retrieve the data from Carousel.js using `useEffect`.

Following this [resource](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/get-data) , Here's the updated and working solution I used.

Carousel.js

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const FetchedImagesFromFirestore = async () => {
      const querySnapshot = await getDocs(
        collection(db, `ImageUrl/${id}/Urls`)
      );
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        setFetchedImages((prevState) => [...prevState, doc.data()]);
      });
    };

    FetchedImagesFromFirestore();
  }, [db]);
```